# How to convert number to dates (by using those number as distance from today date) using pandas datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date

How do I convert number to dates (by using those number as distance from today date). Here's my data

```
    id  Number
    1   -3
    2   -1
    3    6
```

Because of today is `04/07/2019` so it can be converted to

```
    id  Number  date
    1   -3      01/07/2019
    2   -1      03/07/2019
    3    6      10/07/2019
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can achieve this using [`pd.to_timedelta()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=pd+to_timedelta&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=pd+to_timedel&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.3526j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

```
df=df.assign(date=(pd.to_datetime('today')+pd.to_timedelta(df.Number,unit='D')).dt.date)
```

---

```
   id  Number        date
0   1      -3  2019-07-01
1   2      -1  2019-07-03
2   3       6  2019-07-10
```

Answer (score 2):

Quickest way i know by using `.today` and `timedelta` :
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta

```
  import datetime
  numer = -3
  datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days = numer)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'number':[-3,2]})
df['date'] = df['number'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.now() +pd.to_timedelta(x, unit='d') )
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
print(df)
```

```
      number    date
0      -3    2019-07-01
1       2    2019-07-06
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the `today` function from the `datetime.date` class and the `Timedelta` class from Pandas. To format the output like you want, you can use the function `strftime`.

```py
df['date'] = df['Number'].apply(lambda x: (datetime.date.today() + pd.Timedelta('{} days'.format(x))).strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

```py
    Number  date
0   -3      01/07/2019
1   -1      03/07/2019
2   6       10/07/2019
```